# finding and replacing text in a access table column

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to find and replace 'some text' inside a access table column with new data as show below.

this is some text inside column data

```
Update table set column = Replace(column, 'some text', 'new data')
```

this does not work with access databases, is there another way of performing the same action?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

It works in VBA but in SQL you may need to use the WHERE clause; that is, not attempting to use Replace() if the text is not found.

```
Update table set column = Replace(column, 'some text', 'new data') 
WHERE column Like '*some text*'
```

I haven't had a chance to test this though.

It might also be worth putting square brackets around the field-name `Replace([column],`, although this shouldn't really be necessary.

**Added** As you've discovered, you cannot use Replace from C#. You can use other functions - Left, Right, Mid, Trim - but this won't help unless it were a very simple replace (perhaps from the left). Otherwise, you'll need to obtain and loop through an updateable `RecordSet` and perform the replace in C#.

Alternatively, if you have access to the database from within Access, then you could create and save a Query, and use Access-Automation to run (Open) this query. Obtaining an updateable recordset is the better option.

Comment: Having looked into it further, I can not use Replace within a C# application as the Jet Engine does not have the Replace function defined. I still haven't found an answer to this issue, but if someone knows how to get around this it would be greatly appreciated.